# Using the ratio Test to see if a series converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to find if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{3^n}{2^n+1}$ converges or diverges. I am trying to use the ratio test, which gives $\dfrac{3(2^n)+1}{2(2^n)+1}$. I am struggling to rearrange this into a form where it is clear what it tends to as n tends to infinity, or is it just an inconclusive test?

Comment: First use limit comparison with $\sum 3^n/2^n$, and then use the ratio test on the latter.

Comment: even easier: $3^n / 2^n = (3/2)^n \to \infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but the ratio test seems slightly displaced here. Note that, since $\frac{3^n}{2^n+1}\geqslant1$ for every $n\geqslant1$, $\frac{3^n}{2^n+1}$ does not converge to zero, hence the series $\sum\limits_n\frac{3^n}{2^n+1}$ diverges.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$$

So, $$|\frac{3^{n+1}}{2^{n+1} + 1} \cdot \frac{2^n + 1}{3^n}|$$

$$|\frac{3^n \cdot 3}{2^n \cdot 2 + 1} \cdot \frac{2^n + 1}{3^n}|$$

$$|\frac{3 \cdot 2^n + 3}{2 \cdot 2^n +1}|$$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{3 \cdot 2^n + 3}{2 \cdot 2^n +1} = 3/2$$

Since the limit is greater than $1$ the series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the first one:

See that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n}{1+2^{-n}}=\infty$$

Comment: $\ddot\smile +1$